# How to stop reading using >> when there are no more word left

Tags: c++

I am given a list of words in a text file, all seperated by newlines. Reading them using fstream and >>, and not knowing the amount of words there are. How do I tell the program when to stop? I've tested it out, and the value of the variable just stays the same of the last word read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the state of the stream after extraction is always a good idea. It tells you if there were any problems while performing the extraction, or whether the file stream has reached the end-of-file character (`EOF`).

The latter case is what you're dealing with. All you need to do is perform the extraction while the stream is in a good state, which is idiomatically done in the following way:

```
while (in >> str) {
    // ...
}
```

After the stream performs the extraction, `operator bool()` is invoked, which calls `!fail()`. Using a `while` loop will allow the next extraction to be performed automatically. It will stop when the stream has performed an incorrect extraction, is perhaps out of memory, when it hits the `EOF` character, or some other user-defined situation.

Comment: `operator bool()` (or `operator void*()` in pre-C++11) does _not_ test for `good()` (which would make it useless); it returns `!fail()`.  Which does not test for the `eofbit` (which may or may not be set after a successful read).

Answer (score 1):

You've failed the fundamental principle of I/O: You must **check** whether your input operation succeeds. You *cannot* know that in advance, you only learn that after you have tried:

```
for (std::string word; std::cin >> word; )
//                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^<----------- test for success
{
    std::cout << "Here is one word: " << word << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that the input operator `>>` returns the stream it uses, and that streams can be used as boolean conditions. That means you can use it as a loop condition:

```
while (some_stream >> some_variable)
{
    ...
}
```